# How can I list the users which have a game in Steam?

Tags: steam

So, for example. Imagine I want to do some little research: to find out the average time invested in a game by its players.

What I am looking for is a way to get a list of the people who have bought that game. So I can go, one by one and count the hours they have invested in the game.

(not interested in how big is the playerbase, peaks of people playing etc..)

Comment: I'd say its not possible since some users might have their profile in private. Though I'm not a Steam expert

Comment: Not really possible, but a good indicator is actually AStats: http://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=250400 Not everyone is on AStats though, but I think it gives you a good rundown. Keep in mind though that those folks are Achievement Hunters and probably spend more time in a game than the average player. I assume you are a gamedev? If you have lots of achievements in your game, this is your audience anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The steam web API is useful:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetGlobalStatsForGame_.28v0001.29

I haven't tried the second linked method, I also haven't found a good place to look for what parameters you can pass. But I don't think there's any good way to find all the users that own a game if that doesn't work.

Searching for profiles and going through them one by one seems like it would probably take a very long time.

Edit:
Wasn't clear why I believe there to be stats other than achivements accessible through that method:
http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetGlobalStatsForGame
Again, haven't tried it.